# What protocols in a Switch/ Network Equipment come into play, to ensure efficient Multicast support for WDS/ FOG image deployments?

Tags: switch, multicast

Note: 
These are Operating System deployment tools

- WDS - Windows Deployment Services (Not the WiFi WDS)
- FOG - https://fogproject.org/

What **"protocols/ capability/ feature/ technical specs"** become relevant and are leveraged in a  **Switch or Networking equipment** in order to **ensure efficient WDS / FOG multicast based image deployments**.

Every higher layer application depends on some lower layer capabilities. Hence, applications choose to use TCP or UDP based on their design parameters. In this vein, I'd like to know what becomes relevant in networking arena in the above application.

[Can FOG and/ or WDS do multicast over an ordinary unmanaged Gigabit Switch? or does it need hardware with specific multicast features?](https://serverfault.com/questions/791961/can-fog-and-or-wds-do-multicast-over-an-ordinary-unmanaged-gigabit-switch-or-d/792246)

http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=673120

Comment: @RonMaupin - Apologies for the confusion - Updated question - Also, you might need to look at the Linked Question

Comment: I updated my answer to actually answer each question. Some of them are explicitly off-topic here, and you must ask them on the proper SE site.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I tried but it did not allow me to do so earlier. Maybe some time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was posted by [aero](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?members/aero.7525/) as a [reply](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/what-to-look-for-in-a-switch-network-equipment-to-ensure-multicast-support-for-wds-fog-image-depl.12004/#post-113874) and makes sense:

> You don't need a special or managed switch. However, it would be **preferable for your switch to support [IGMP Snooping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping)**. That will **prevent the multicast traffic from being transmitted on every port**. Instead, it will **only be delivered to ports where there is a listener**.

If you are running an **access point in the same vlan you're trying to use multicast**, and **don't have an IGMP snooping capable switch**, you WILL **completely congest your wifi frequencies. It will completely cripple your wireless network when you try to use multicast**.

Secondly, if you are trying to do this over a **routed network** (rather than all hosts in the same vlan), then you will need a **router that supports the [PIM protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Independent_Multicast)**.

Comment: As I wrote, all switches can handle multicast, which is a form of layer-2 broadcast. I also wrote that you need to enable multicast routing on a router if you want to multicast to a different network. I really don't see what you have is any different than what I wrote in the context of your question. All enterprise-grade switches and routers can handle multicast, so, no, you don't need anything special.

Comment: @RonMaupin My question was looking for specifics, on what protocol/ capability must a switch have. I appreciate your answer, but it didn't give specifics on the 2 things listed by aero. Also, do "all switches" in the world support multi casting? I doubt it, as I've heard people experience otherwise when using WDS. Anyways, I appreciate your help, but now I'm more secure in knowing exact 2 key named features that play into the scenario.

Comment: As I have explained to you multiple times, ethernet, meaning ethernet switches, support multicast. Also, as I have explained, your last link says, "_Commercial-grade switches provide a mechanism to regulate where the multicasts go to conserve bandwidth._" That may be a nice but unnecessary feature, depending on your network design, but it can cause problems, too, based on your design. As far as PIM goes, commercial-grade routers support it or another form of multicast routing. Consumer-grade devices are unlikely to support either.

Comment: The equipment that is on-topic here supports everything you need to do what you want. You may not need either of the two "special" features that are already built into commercial-grade equipment.